# Involution on $l^1(G)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am new to all of this material and have questions of the type "what just happened?"
Some definitions at first.
For algebra $\mathcal{A}$ over $\mathbb{C}$, involution is a map $*:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ with the properties:

1. $(a^*)^* = a$
2. $(a^* + b^*) = (a + b)^*$
3. $(\alpha a)^* = \bar{\alpha} a^*$
4. $(ab)^* = b^* a^*$

A unitary representation of a discrete group $G$ on Hilbert space $H$ is a homomorphism $\pi : G \rightarrow \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{H})$, set of unitary operators on $\mathcal{H}$.

Now to the results I have questions about. In the lecture we noted that $C_C(G)$, function s of compact support on $G$, form a subalgebra of $l_1(G)$, a set of bounded sequences in $\mathbb{C}$. We defined
$$ \pi_f = \sum _{x \in G} f(x) \pi_x $$
I have no idea why we would want to define this object, but I understand it is a unitary operator on $H$. Then we found $(\pi_f)^*$. It is an adjoint of $\pi_f$ on a Hilbert space, and I know it is uniquely defined by the condition
$$ <\pi_f (h), g>_H  = <h,\pi_f^*(g)>_H$$
But we found it as follows:
$$ (\pi_f)^* = \sum _{x \in G} \overline{f(x)} \pi_x^* = \sum _{x \in G} \overline{f(x)} \pi_{x^{-1}} = \sum _{x \in G} \overline{f(x^{-1})} \pi_x $$
Neither of the equalities makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: If I'm guessing, the goal of your class here is to show that unitary representations of $G$ are in one-one correspondence with (non-degenerate) $*$-representations of $\ell^1(G)$. This is why we care about $\pi_f$. It explains how to associate with every representation $\pi$, a $*$-representation of $\ell^1(G)$. The first equality you write is just the fact that involution is continuous and antilinear. The second equality uses that $\pi_x^* = \pi_{x}^{-1}= \pi_{x^{-1}}$, since $\pi_x$ is a unitary and $\pi$ is a group morphism, and the last equality is just the substitution $x\mapsto x^{-1}$.

Comment: The operator $\pi_f$ is well defined as the series on the RHS defining it, is absolutely convergent in $B(H).$

Comment: @J.DeRo thanks, very helpful! What is a *-representation?

Comment: @AnnaVakarova An algebra homomorphism that preserves the involution with codomain bounded operators on a Hilbert space.